# Long broadcast time in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast

I have the following Spark code to broadcast a big `Array[Array[Int]] data`.

```
val timeBeg = System.currentTimeMillis

val dataBc = sc.broadcast(data)

rdd.mapPartitions(_ => Iterator(dataBc.value.length)).count()

val timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis

println((timeEnd - timeBeg) / 1000.0)
```

Here, `rdd.mapPatitions(...).count()` is used to immediately broadcast `data`. The code took about 35 seconds. However, when I looked at the Spark UI, I found that the `count` in `rdd.mapPartitions(...).count()` took only 11 seconds, which means that `sc.broadcast(data)` took about 24 seconds. If I understand correctly, Spark broadcasts `data` in a lazy manner, thus `sc.broadcast(data)` should be a cheap operation and should not take that much time (24 seconds). Am I missing something?

**Update:** After tuning gc, the total time cost by the code above reduces to about 24 seconds. `sc.broadcast` still needs about 10 seconds.